# How to form JSON path

Tags: json, syntax

I have employers array as below; how to get employers:id and featuredReview:id using JSON expression.

```
"employers": [
      {
        "id": 194,
        "name": "Target",
        "website": "www.target.com",
        "isEEP": false,
        "exactMatch": false,
        "industry": "Department, Clothing, & Shoe Stores",
        "numberOfRatings": 11531,
        "squareLogo": "http://media.glassdoor.com/sqll/194/target-squarelogo.png",
        "overallRating": 3.2,
        "ratingDescription": "OK",
        "cultureAndValuesRating": "3.3",
        "seniorLeadershipRating": "2.8",
        "compensationAndBenefitsRating": "3.0",
        "careerOpportunitiesRating": "3.0",
        "workLifeBalanceRating": "3.0",
        "recommendToFriendRating": "0.6",
        "featuredReview": {
          "id": 6613365,
          "currentJob": false,
          "reviewDateTime": "2015-05-15 16:32:06.997",
          "jobTitle": "Executive Team Leader",
          "location": "Buena Park, CA",
          "jobTitleFromDb": "Executive Team Leader",
          "headline": "Unrealistic expectations for leadership",
          "overall": 4,
          "overallNumeric": 4
        },
        "ceo": {
          "name": "Brian Cornell",
          "title": "CEO",
          "numberOfRatings": 1127,
          "pctApprove": 66,
          "pctDisapprove": 34
        }
      }]
```

Comment: JASON? What language are you using? You never really access raw JSON, just like you don't access raw XML. You parse it into a native data structure of the language you are processing the data with and access that data structure.

Comment: I also have never heard about a "JSON expression". What is that? Or are you just using incorrect terminology?

Answer (score 1):

1. employers[0].id
2. employers[0].featuredReview.id

Comment: That's invalid syntax in PHP. What language is that supposed to be?